# Questions on its Use so i can know which scheduler to use

Tags: spring, spring-batch, scheduler, job-scheduling, spring-batch-admin

Hi I am new to schedulers and I am looking for certain features in schedulers that i will need. Does Spring Batch support the following:

UI

•   support for monitoring job status
•   initiating ad hoc jobs
•   setting up and modifying regularly scheduled jobs

Scripting

•   what scripting languages does it support
•   does it have an API for loading scripts

Capabilities

•   chaining
•   dependencies
•   error handling
Support
•   Is there a commercial version with support

Any help regarding these points is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and this 
http://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how to post a good question.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/ which is a job scheduling library for Java applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringBatch is not a scheduler. SpringBatch is a framework based on Spring to implement Batch-Jobs in Java.

This jobs can then be run by a scheduler like streamworks, but 
jobscheduling is not part of SpringBatch, and hence, all your questions can be answered with 'no'.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your exact requirements but from the question it looks you are looking something in addition to mere scheduler capabilities. Please find the answers to specific questions below with respect to spring batch

UI

You can use spring batch admin to monitor initiate the jobs and monitor the status. You might have to use a cron or someother scheduler to schedule your jobs

Scripting

Spring batch has support for invoking a  grrovy script from the batch job . you can invoke a spring batch job from a shell script or a groovy script.

Capabilities

you can configure a job with multiple steps with dependency between the steps.You can also define a job with parallel flows. I hope this is what you might be looking with respect to chaining and dependencies. 
not sure the exact nature of error handing you are looking at. you might have to go through the reference documentation to analyse in detail if spring batch suits your requirement. http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/index.html

There are no commerical versions of spring batch.